# Chrome don't render nested asp.net mvc ajax form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, jquery

Have need to implement nested ajax form in another ajax form. In IE all works fine - child form appear and work good, in Firefox child form work but replace full page, but in Chrome nested forms don't render anyway. Is there any workaround for this issue?
I can implement all logic with jquery.ajax but prefer to find solution in "classic" way. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested Forms are not in html standard so you should avoid use it. Browsers works with nested forms in different way and it is not a bug.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I need to correct my mind - I was absolutely sure that browsers should work correctly with nested forms until today. Now re-read article from Sanderson and saw that he warn about this problem.

Comment: It used to work till date in our application where we were using InPlaceEditor which adds Form element .... God knows why did it stop in the LIVE application now !

Comment: If this answer helps you, you can plus this answer.